# How tiring is riding the bullhorns?

Tags: handlebars, riding-position, pain, comfort

I was wondering if anyone here who is riding with bullhorn handlebars could share how tiring it is to ride, say, 50 km? I am thinking of setting up them to my road bike, mainly because, you know, it looks cool, but it almost feels like riding on drops which I find uncomfortable after a while. Bullhorn handlebars also provide 2 positions, so, does that make it more manageable? I am interested in rides which are about 30 - 70 km long. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried riding on the hoods?

Comment: Sure, but the bullhorn equivalent to hood riding would require the rider to stretch more, right? In other words, shouldn't the "hoods" on the bullhorn be further away from the rider than on the dropbar (for the stem of equal length)?

Comment: That's true, but I don't see how that's relevant. Drop bars are hands down the best for long rides, because there are three different hand positions. When you get tired of the drops, move to the hoods. I'm not sure why you'd want to reduce your options by moving to bullhorns

Comment: Bullhorns are not meant for long rides. They are mean to help gain speed by giving the rider a better aero dynamic position. That's why you see them on track bikes which race for a few laps/miles as opposed to bikes on the tour De France where they ride for long hours/miles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use bullhorns on my fixed gear commuter bike, and sometimes get some hand fatigue/numbness because of the position.  As with everything, everyone will have different experiences because physiology.  But it's been my experience the most comfortable position is in the curve forward.  The forward position is close in comfort to riding on the hoods on normal drop bars.  If comfort is your aim, you will probably get more mileage(get it?) out of better tape or a nice set of gloves.